HTTP API call works despite cleartextTrafficPermitted="false" in Android app with minimum SDK 29 and Flutter 3.22.3
I'm facing an issue where an HTTP API call is still working on my Android app despite configuring the app to block cleartext traffic. Below are the details:
Configuration:
AndroidManifest.xml:
I have added the following in my AndroidManifest.xml file to disallow cleartext traffic:
<application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="false"
    ...>
</application>

Network Security Config (network_security_config.xml):
I have created a network_security_config.xml file with the following configuration to ensure no cleartext traffic is permitted:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false" />
</network-security-config>

API Call (Dio):
I am making an HTTP request to an AWS-hosted API that does not have HTTPS and does not perform any HTTPS redirection:
try {
    AppFileLogger.writeErrorLog("Got response.", "Dashboard", "Calling................................................");
    Dio _dio = Dio();

    final response = await _dio.get('http://13.*****.232:8080/****');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        AppFileLogger.writeErrorLog("Got response.", "Dashboard", "=====> ${response.data}");
    } else {
        AppFileLogger.writeErrorLog("Got response.", "Dashboard", "=====> ${response.statusCode} - ${response.data}");
    }
} catch (error) {
    AppFileLogger.writeErrorLog("Got response.", "Dashboard", "=====> $error");
}

Device Information:

Device: Real device Samsung Motorola (Android 14)
Minimum SDK: 29
Flutter Version: 3.22.3
App runs: Release mode

Problem: Despite the network security configuration and the fact that the API is HTTP (not HTTPS), the API call works and I receive a response. The API is hosted on AWS and does not have SSL certificates or HTTPS redirection.

Why is the HTTP call working despite the security configurations to
block cleartext traffic?

Could this issue be specific to Flutter or the Android version
(Android 14)?

Are there any other settings or configurations I should check to
ensure that HTTP calls are blocked in my app?


Any help or insights would be appreciated!

For Dio you have to use the native_dio_adapter package which uses the native backed Cronet and Cupertino http clients. Those enforce the native restrictions, like the usesCleartextTraffic setting in the manifest.
This is explained in the http package's "Choosing an implementation" part. The default Dart backed IOClient is very limited.
